# Zend Framework 2.0 translate validators

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-validate, zend-translate

I'm trying to translate errors in validator, but i have problems..

```
$translator = new Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator();
$translator->addTranslationFile(
    'phpArray',
    'resources/languages/en.php',
    'default',
    'en_US'
);
Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

Doesn't work, i recieve error

`Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in DIR\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator.php on line 228`

228 line is:

```
$this->locale = Locale::getDefault();
```

when i set it to:

```
$this->locale = 'pl_PL';
```

error disappear but validator isn't translated..

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the intl PHP extension.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl (for linux)
```

Restart your php after installing.